# Pointer Array Over Then 650k Element

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, size

I have an integer array list and I want to make left right pointer array list to access this. But for more than 690.000 elements (for example 700.000) the program stops and says `Segmentation fault (core dumped). I have used std::vector before but I have to use simple array list because of speed. And This code is not about my program it is very simple way to tell my problem with code. And I have to use global variable because this code run in a class methods.

```
int k=698900;


int n1=k/2;
int n2=k/2;
int *left[n1];
int *right[n2]; 
int list[k];

for(int i=0; i<k; i++){
    list[i] = i;
}

for(int i=0; i<n1; i++){
    left[i] = &list[i];
}

for(int i=0; i<n2; i++){
    right[i] = &list[i];
}

for(int i=0; i<n2; i++){
    cout << *right[i] << endl;
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell from your code fragment, but my guess is that you made these all local variables and so you are getting a classic stack overflow.

Comment: @PaulR which leads us to the 2 possible solutions of either increasing the stack size or allocating the arrays on the heap (by using a `std::vector` for example). Edit: or the third one @PaulR mentioned :P

Comment: Or make the arrays static/global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @PaulR already said in the comments your problem is a stack overflow. You can solve this problems a few ways. If you're categorically against changing your code then you can adjust the stack size in your compiler. How exactly that is done depends on your compiler ([gcc example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275550/change-stack-size-for-a-c-application-in-linux-during-compilation-with-gnu-com) and [VS example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdkhxaks.aspx)). You can also adjust it at run-time but that's an OS dependent function, so I'm not going to go into details about that.

The solution that I would prefer is allocate the memory on the heap. This can be done by either allocating the arrays on the heap `int **left = new int*[n1];` but then you have to remember to call `delete []left;` when you don't need the memory anymore. The far more elegant solution would be to use a `std::vector` instead.

I challenge you to compile this with all optimizations on and tell me that it's significantly slower than your code.

```
int k=698900;


int n1=k/2;
int n2=k/2;
//not that I condone storing raw pointers in a vector
//admittedly this is a rather dangerous thing to do
//storing indices would be smarter because upon adding
//elements the memory could be relocated
std::vector<int *> left(n1);  
std::vector<int *> right(n2); 
std::vector<int> list(k);

for(int i=0; i<k; i++){
    list[i] = i;
}

for(int i=0; i<n1; i++){
    left[i] = &list[i];
}

for(int i=0; i<n2; i++){
    right[i] = &list[i];
}

for(int i=0; i<n2; i++){
    cout << *right[i] << endl;
}
```

Like @PaulR mentioned you can also allocate the arrays statically (`static int *left[n1];`) or globally (outside of any function or class declaration/definition)

Comment: Thank you for reply that is what I want :) int **left = new int*[n1]; I wonder what is the difference between this (int **left = new int*[n1];) and this ( int *left[n1];)

Comment: the difference is very well explained [in other places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713637/heap-vs-stack-allocation). Like I said, one is called stack allocation and the other is heap allocation.

Comment: I see but I wonder difference between stack allocation and the other :) anyway thanks you I can google it.